# プログラムのみで完全にランダムな乱数を生成することは可能ですか？

Tags: random

ランダムな値を返すメソッドを調べていてふと気がついたのですが、プログラムのみで完全にランダムな値を返すことは可能なのでしょうか？

乱数の生成にはシード値が必要となりますよね。時間をミリ秒まで拡大した値をシード値にしたり、タスクのプロセスIDをシード値にしたりすることでかなりユニークなシード値は手に入ります。しかし、ソフトウェアの仕様上、ミリ秒やプロセスIDが判明すればシード値が判明するわけであり、完全にランダムなシード値は得られなくなりますよね。

こういった性質をふまえたうえで、プログラムやソフトウェアのみで完全にランダムなシード値を獲得する方法はあるのでしょうか？ プログラムだけではなく特別な装置やハードウェアが必要になってくるのでしょうか？

Comment: ここで言っている「プログラムのみ」というのは、具体的にどういう環境を想定していますか？例えば普通の物理的なパソコンで動作しているUbuntu 20.04LTSで、パソコンに必要な機器類(ディスプレイ、キーボード、マウス等)以外のハードウェアがついていない状態で、CやPython等の一般的なプログラム言語を用いて作られたソフトウェアのみであれば、「プログラムのみ」としますか？そのような環境を想定すると"/dev/random"を使うとか、CPUのRDRAND命令を使うとか、そういうことも有りになってしまいます。では"/dev/random"が使えないとしても、Linuxカーネルがしている"/dev/random"の実装と同じことをすれば良いという話にもなってきます。ですので、そういったハードウェア(パソコン)やOSや用意するものやそれらに由来するものは全て使用してはならない(たとえば、現在時刻の取得も元々はハードウェア上のクロックからの値であるので、使用してはならない)と考えてよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 実は情報工学ではなく数学での回答がほしいですか？キーワードとしては真の乱数や疑似乱数というのが浮かびますが

Comment: @raccy 標準的に備え付けられているハードウェアであれば、プログラムから標準的に使えるはずなので、それはプログラムからも利用可能と考えます。一般的な構成のハードウェアでプログラミングするうえで、(標準のライブラリやハードウェアを使った上で)プログラムから完全にランダムな乱数を手に入れたいんです。

Comment: @keitaro_so すみません、こちらの知識不足で情報工学と数学における乱数の知識が足りないため、(ざっくりとあらゆる分野を横断して)完全にランダムな乱数を手に入れる方法はないものかという質問になります。ですが、強いて言うなら、情報工学の世界における乱数の生成方法の質問になると思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どこまでを「特別な装置やハードウェア」と考えるかは人それぞれなので、参考情報として。

プログラムは書いた通りにしか動作しないため、ランダムとて書かれた通りの動作をするだけです。何らかの外部情報が必要です。

2012年発表の[Ivy Bridgeマイクロアーキテクチャ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3)以降には乱数ジェネレータが搭載され、それを呼び出す[`RDRAND`命令 / `RDSEED`命令](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND)が用意されています。C/C++言語からは[`_rdrand64_step`等](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Random)の関数名で呼び出すことが可能です。

OSレベルでは、Linuxを中心に[`/dev/random`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)が用意されています。またWindowsにおいても暗号ライブラリの一部として[`CryptGenRandom`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom) APIが用意されています。どのような実装が行われるかはプラットフォーム依存ではありますが、アプリケーションから見れば、そこそこにランダムな値が得られることが期待されています。

C++言語の[`<random>`乱数ライブラリ](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/random.html)には[`std::random_device`クラス](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/random/random_device.html)が用意されています。どのような実装が行われるかはやはりプラットフォーム依存ではありますが、`RDRAND`や`/dev/random`等が使われることが想定されています。

Answer (score 4):

> プログラムやソフトウェアのみで完全にランダムなシード値を獲得する方法はあるのでしょうか？ プログラムだけではなく特別な装置やハードウェアが必要になってくるのでしょうか？

大雑把な答えとしては：ソフトウェアのみで真にランダムなシード値を得る方法はありません。

IPAサイトにある [RFC1750 セキュリティのための乱雑性についての推奨事項(Randomness Recommendations for Security)](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/rfc/RFC1750JA.html) が参考になると思います。要旨(Abstract)より一部引用します：

> これは、真に乱雑なハードウェアによるテクニックの利用を推奨し、「多くのシステム上の既存のハードウェアは、この目的のために使うことができること」を示します。これは、ハードウェアによる解決策が不能であるとき、問題を改善するための示唆を提供します。そして、これは、「何らかの特定のアプリケーションのために、このような数は、どの位大きい必要があるか」の例を与えます。

ハードウェア以外の手段として、ユーザ（ヒト）の操作情報を用いることもあります。一部の鍵生成ツールでは、ユーザにランダムなキー入力をさせたり、マウスカーソルをぐりぐり動かさせたりという要求を行うものがあります。

- [公開鍵暗号を利用した認証 (PuTTY)](https://www.st.ryukoku.ac.jp/security/ssh/win/publickey.html)